# maximum likelihood regression when error term is truncated

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

I consider a binary regression model.
$$y_i = 1\{bx_i + e_i>0\}, $$
where $e_i$ is drawn from truncated normal distribution with mean zero, unit variance, and truncated above by $x_i$.

To estimate $b$, I form log likelihood as follows:
$$L(b) = \sum_i\left(y_i\log\int 1\{bx_i + e_i>0\}\,d\Phi_i(e_i) + (1-y_i)\log \int 1\{bx_i + e_i<0\}\,d\Phi_i(e_i)   \right),$$
where $\Phi_i(\cdot)$ is a truncated normal distribution with parameters discribed above.

Then, I simulated the model, setting $b=1$. I get $\hat{b} \approx 2.3$. I assume that truncated normal of $e_i$ is the problem.

How should I fix the MLE to get unbiased estimates?

Comment: What do you mean by this notation?

Comment: @Tim which one?